# Console does not display build or error messages

Tags: console

Eclipse console does not display build or error messages.
Right click on maven pom.xml -> run as maven install -> only  information is displayed, not the whole build success messages.

Java application system out messages are getting displayed.

I tried window -> perspective -> reset perspective.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What should I do so that these messages get displayed on the console?  Thanks